# Java WeakHashMap with multiple keys?

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, hashmap

I'm looking for an equivalent to the

```
WeakHashMap<K, V>
```

class, except that it maps multiple keys to a value, so it's really more like

```
WeakHashMap<K1, K2, V>
WeakHashMap<K1, K2, K3, V>
etc.
```

The way you `get` and `set` entries would be like a multi-column primary key in a database: you put items using multiple keys e.g. `(K1, K2)`, and to get that item back out you need to provide *all* the same keys you used to put it in. Given these `get` & `set` semantics, the GC semantics would be: an entry would be GCed when no longer reachable, which means that *any* of its keys is no longer reachable.

Has anyone else needed something like this before? How would you approach such a requirement? Storing a Tuple as the key, like you could do in a non-weak HashMap, doesn't work (the Tuple gets GCed almost immediately, with nobody pointing to it).

If something like this has been made before I'd be happy to use it, but just trying to think of how I would construct such a thing out of WeakReferences and a normal hashmap and am coming up with a blank.

Comment: Why can't you just wrap the `WeakHashMap` in your own class that builds the composite key as a single string or object (with `equals()` and `hashCode()`)?

Comment: Because that new composite-key will have nobody referencing it, and will get GCed as soon as i chuck it into the weak hash map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I don't know of any implementations of this, but I would approach it by adapting the source for `WeakHashMap`. It uses a `ReferenceQueue` and polls it at the start of pretty much every public method, removing entries for every gc'ed referent.

Here's my rough outline of how to adapt `WeakHashMap` to be a multi-key weak map:

1. Define a compound key like you described and use it for the main entry set
2. Maintain an internal map from key component to the set of keys in which it participates
3. When you find a referent component on the `ReferenceQueue`, look up the set of keys in which it participates and remove those keys from the main entry set
4. You also need to remove each of the keys in which it participates from every other key component's set. That is, suppose you find a key component c<sub>1</sub> on the reference queue and it participates in keys k<sub>1</sub>, ..., k<sub>n</sub>. Then for each k<sub>i</sub>, if the other key components are c<sub>2</sub> and c<sub>3</sub>, you need to remove k<sub>i</sub> from the key sets for c<sub>2</sub> and c<sub>3</sub>, as well as remove the entire entry for c<sub>1</sub>.
5. When a key set for a component is empty, you should probably also remove the key set map entry for that component. That means that you may find a component on the reference queue that has no corresponding data in the component-to-key-set map.

The fly in the ointment here is that all these internal maps must be set up in a way that will not prevent a key component from being gc'ed. That is, there must be no hard (or soft) references within this multi-key-map structure. `WeakHashMap` accomplishes this by making its internal `Entry` class (that implements `Map.Entry`) extend `WeakReference`. When a key is gc'ed, it is the `Entry` object, not the key itself, that is placed in the reference queue. Something like this would have to be used in the design of all the internal structures (the compound key object, the entry set, the map from key component to the set of keys, and the set of keys themselves).